# News-API not working in Chrome but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, api, cors, cors-anywhere

```
    const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" 
    const url =`${proxyUrl}http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-05-28&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=${key}`; 
    const request = new Request(url);
 fetch(request) .then(response => response.json())
             .then((news) => 
             { console.log(news); }) 
             .catch(error => 
             { console.log(error); });
```

why this code is showing following error in Chrome and properly working in Firefox?

> code: "corsNotAllowed"
> message: "Requests from the browser are not
> allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."

Answer (score 1):

Chrome adds the `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` header, but Firefox does not. If I add the `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site` to the Firefox request the error is returned. So it seems like newsapi.org checks this header and blocks requests with it on the "Developer plan".

Comment: So in order to use in chrome , do we have to use paid plan? Or is there any other way?

Comment: @SiddhantJain, you cannot change this header in the JS because it is the forbidden header name, according to the returned message there is a single straightforward way to use this service in Chrome it is either to use localhost or to have another plan.